# website is opening from that section where I left it

Tags: javascript, html

I have my portfolio website where I have put links to another section like this

```html
<a href="#contact">Contact me</a>
```

and I have also added preloader to my website.
Now there are my social media links in contact me section of my website.So when I click on them it redirects me to my social media profile.

```html
<a href="social media link">Social media</a>
```

But the problem is when I come back from the social media account to my portfolio site again, in spite of opening at home section it is directly jumping to contact me section. and the url-bar is showing like this
**http://1xx.0.0.1:5500/index.html#contact**

So how can I prevent this?

Comment: How are javascript, css and xmlhttprequest involved in the question?

Comment: What do you mean by coming back? are you clicking a link or the back button

Comment: I mean the back arrow button of browser

Comment: The back button takes you to the previous location. That's the expected behavior, and I wouldn't try to change it, because it's confusing when web pages are messing with your browser behavior.

Comment: So should I use target="__blank" in link tag so that it opens in new tab.

Comment: The position would still be on the hash when you're returning to your page.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of a workaround but if it doesn't conflict with other functions of your page you could redirect the user on pageload

```
window.onload = function() {
  window.location.replace("http://1xx.0.0.1:5500/index.html");
}
```

Comment: The url-bar changed but it is still opening on contact section. I mean it is scrolling down to bottom and reaching the section where I previously was.

Comment: then you can try this `window.location.href = "http://1xx.0.0.1:5500/index.html";` in the function body instead. This works like as you would click a link.